# lxml will not allow me to collect the text between hyperlink tags in an html document

Tags: python, hyperlink, lxml, python-requests

**EDIT: I noticed the text I am looking for is actually loading a moment or two after the rest of the page completes loading. I found I am able to gather all the info I want except for this and one other tag which is also delayed in loading. I couldn't really figure out what was causing the delay, and a new feature was added to the site that let me get the info I was scrapping for in a report. I am no longer looking to solve this strange circumstance as I have what I needed, but don't want to delete the question.**

**Md. Mohsin's answer would work for more normalized circumstances, so I have marked his answer as correct because it answers the actual question asked rather than my specific situation, which I did not properly understand or express. /EDIT**

I am trying to get the text that displays between hyperlink tags. An email address in this particular case.

For instance:

```
<tr>
    <td class="txtXSmall" align="right">Name: </td>
    <td id="showContactName" class="txtSmall" align="left">John Snow</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="txtXSmall" align="right">Email: </td>
    <td class="txtSmall" align="left">
        <a id="contactEmail" href="#">I WANT THIS RIGHT HERE</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am getting the page through requests, and then using html from lxml to parse it.

```
def GetOrderData(orderID):
    ## password
    payload = {'pass': 'password', 'user': 'user','submit':'go'}  ## Log in Paramaters
    ## page
    r = requests.get("http://website.com/order.php?orderID="+str(orderID), params=payload) ##Get Order Page
    ## html analyzed
    tree = html.fromstring(r.text)  ## turn raw string into html tagged data
    return tree
```

I have tried the following:

Using the most specific xpath possible

```
>>>rawdata = tree.xpath("/html/body/form[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div[1]/section/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/a")
>>>print rawdata
[]
```

Going for the block of text this link is a part of.

```
>>>rawdata = tree.xpath(".//*[@id='show_contact']")
>>>print rawdata[0].text_content()
prints the whole grouped block of text that is outside of the <a> tag
```

Going for it's specific ID

```
>>>rawdata = tree.xpath(".//*[@id='contactEmail']")
>>>rawdata[0].text_content()
''
>>>rawdata[0].text
```

I have tried several other things not well documented, but to no avail.

Is lxml capable of accomplishing my goal?

If not, are there other libraries that I can use instead?

As a final hope, is there a way to follow a link with lxml or requests?

although the link has 'href = "#"', it takes me here:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/stuff/mailto:EMAIL ADDRESS THAT I WANT?stuff
```

If I could get that link to activate and then capture the url of the page it takes me to, I may be able to get the text that I am after.

Thank you.

** Edit **

Below is a wider look at the html

```
<div class="ui-box">
  <header>
    <section>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td width="99%" valign="top">
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="100%">
                      <div id="show_contact">
                        <table class="txtGray" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                          <tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="txtXSmall" align="right">Email: </td>
                            <td class="txtSmall" align="left">
                              <a id="contactEmail" href="#">I WANT TO CAPTURE THIS</a>
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                         <tr>
                       </tbody>
                     </table>
                   </div>
                 <div id="edit_contact" style="display: none;">
               </td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </td>
       <td align="right" width="1%" valign="top">
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Using your html fragment as source, `tree.find("tr/td/a[@id='contactEmail']").text` works for me.

Comment: That is giving me an Attribute Error that NoneType objects do not have a text attribute.

Comment: I said "using your HTML fragment as source" - you didn't post the full HTML document. And the point is that lxml works fine, your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used your wider look html in place of `r.text`

```
import lxml.html

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)
print tree.xpath('//*[@id="contactEmail"]//text()')


Out[]: ['I WANT TO CAPTURE THIS']
```

Hope that helps :-)